# QT´s generated exe cannot connect to PostrgreSQL Database

Tags: c++, qt

I´m developing an application in QT 5.4 that connects to a Postrgre DB. When Running the application in release mode inside QT Creator the connection works fine. However, when I add the dependencies of the .exe and open it I always get a connection error. I added the QT5Sql.dll to the release directory and all the other needed dependencies according to dependency walker.

Can anyone tell me what I´m doing wrong?

```
ui->setupUi(this);
finishedGame = false;
ui->detener->setVisible(false);
ui->labelEnCurso->setVisible(false);
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setDatabaseName("MYDB");
db.setUserName("USER");
db.setPassword("PASS");
bool ok = db.open();
if(!ok){

    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText("Connection ERROR");
    msgBox.exec();
}
```

**UPDATE**

I checked the .exe with DebugView and this is the error I get:

```
[10876] QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded
[10876] QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

I have both the libpq.dll and the qsqlpsql.dll on my release folder, however for some reason the app cannot load the appropriate drivers although it is saying it´s available.

Comment: Do you have `sqldrivers` directory with appropriate .dll for PostgreSQL? It can be found in `plugins` directory of your Qt installation. You can also try [DebugView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896647.aspx) to see what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I already added the sqldrivers. But I´ll try DebugView out :)

Comment: You could also set environment variable `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` and check output in DebugView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. Just in case anyone comes across the same problem. I solved it by adding all the contents of the bin folder in the PostgreSQL installation Directory to my release folder of the QT project.